# How to move progress bar during custom action

Tags: wix, action

While running the custom action in the installer there is no progress bar. We are using the Immediate C# manage code custom action.

Is any other ways to show the progress while running the custom action ?

Advance thanks 
\
Velu

Comment: dont know if it will help but you can look at this post, maybe it will give you some ideas. 

http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?t=187309

Answer (score 1):

Use ProgressText element.

The 'Template' attribute is the place to put tokens to reflect the progress. See the standard InstallFiles action for example. The table "ActionData messages" lists the possible tokens for this action.

Sample:

```
<ProgressText Action="InstallFiles" Template="File: [9][1]">!(loc.InstallFilesActionText)</ProgressText>
```

Outputs:

File: C:\Program Files\MyApp\bin\my.dll

etc.